# PuTTY flooded with broadcast messages

Tags: command-line, broadcasting

I hired someone through fiverr to upgrade my Ubuntu system, saving the email and webpages hosted there. He accomplished the upgrade, but not successfully. Now when I log in via PuTTY, I get a constant stream of broadcast messages from the mailserver app. I'm unable to get anything done.

Any suggestions on how to stop the messages?

Comment: Note: I'm able to input commands I can't see. I've tried `ps -ef > /tmp/test.txt`, but only get an empty file. If I could get that output I might be able to do a kill command.

Comment: Ok, I finally just used WinSCP to go in and delete the mailserver executable, then rebooted and no longer have that problem.